# youtube-dl package - Python, SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, homebrew, youtube-dl

I installed youtube-dl using pip `sudo pip install youtube-dl`and the install was successful. 
When I run import youtube-dl from a python script, it says invalid syntax.

```
python youtube_downloader.py
File "youtube_downloader.py", line 1
import youtube-dl
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried upgrading the same, with `sudo pip install youtube-dl --upgrade`. It says requirement already satisfied.

`Requirement already up-to-date: youtube-dl in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`

I removed the package and installed `youtube-dl` with `brew install youtube-dl` also. The same thing again, installation was successful but when I import, it says syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have the `-` sign in `import` statements, as the interpreter thinks you are trying to subtract.

Use an underscore instead:

```
>> import youtube_dl
>>
```

This is also described in the [documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#developer-instructions).

Comment: `>>> import youtube_dl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named youtube_dl`

Comment: @geek_code This works for me: `>>> import youtube_dl
>>>`

Are you sure you are running the same Python for which you installed `youtube-dl`?

Comment: yeah..python 2.7. But I don't see any folder of `youtube_dl` in `/Python/2.7/site-packages` but it says package installed.

Comment: @geek_code  What is the output of `pip show youtube_dl` ?

Comment: @geek_code no output means the package wasn't installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and I found the answer for my case.
Personally, when I used the `pip install youtube-dl` command, it gave me a Warning message about the location of my youtube-dl file.

But when I went to the right place, here in "site-packages" it was there.

I then realized that it was neither the localization nor Visual Studio Code but that I had several versions of python, e.g. python 3.6, 3.9.9, 3.10

So I uninstalled the versions I didn't want, so i reinstalled youtube-dl and imported it and it worked!